# Webform + Translations

Tags: 7, webforms, i18n-l10n

I have a website where 80% of it are [Webforms](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform). Admins can create webforms themselves and registered users can fill them in. ( A PDF will be created etc etc...).

Now I have to make this website in 3 other languages then the default.

I Found already the following module:

https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_localization

**Now my initial question:**

Imagine you have a webform in the wizard with  a label, and a textarea and a default value as type or static text. What is the best way to get the 'default' values in the context translated?

**Example**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4uLi.png

Note: 
This is text which got changed for every webform generated on the website.

Answer (score 1):

This is content - not static text; your only options are to translate it manually yourself or use one of the contrib modules like [Lingotek](https://www.drupal.org/project/lingotek) or [Cloudwords](https://www.drupal.org/project/cloudwords).

Answer (score 0):

If you use Entity Translation (recommended), you can use the [Webform Translation](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_translation) module.